# why the size of my apk on windows is different from the one given by unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, size

I have several questions about my apk's size, first why the apk's size shown in the Editor Log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udEz1.png) is different than the one shown on my windows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGk1g.png)? Second I know the "Complete build size" in the Editor Log contains also the size of unity engine'core, but 75.9mb seems too much, is this normal (I'm using unity 2021.3.1f1) ? And the last one, which shown size should I take into consideration if I want to publish my game to a platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you closely look at build report size, it adds up approximately to the size of your .apk file size. It's the apk file size that you should consider. And if you're uploading to Playstore, the .abb the file you want to upload. Additionally, if you want to reduce the build size further, consider compressing your assets.

Answer (score 0):

this is normal unity just show you the uncompressed size of the apk file